# Maximum coins collected by travelling rows in a matrix

Tags: algorithm

input:

- a matrix of non-negative numbers.
- `m` rows, `n` columns.

process:

- start from the first row, select one column `i` and collect the coins there.
- move to the next row, select another column `j`, with cost `|i-j|`, and collect the coins.
- stop after the last row.

output:

- the maximum coins collected.

is there a `O(mn)` algorithm for this problem?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to post your code (even if suboptimal) or at least some of the things you've tried in solving the problem when asking questions, to get the most helpful response. [Nonetheless, this is a common dynamic programming interview question](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-number-of-points-with-cost/), so there are places to get started looking for the `O(mn)` algorithm.

Comment: @kcsquared depending how one looks at it, the discussion section of leetcode is either enlightening or takes away all the fun :)

Answer (score 0):

We are supposed to have a matrix[n][m] (n - rows, m - columns).
Let's determine i<sub>n</sub>j<sub>m</sub> as a sum of a column starting from a i<sub>n</sub>j<sub>m</sub> coordinates in a matrix to the end of the matrix.
Let's introduce this statement as the first sum:
*Σ<sub>1</sub> = i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>1</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>2</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>3</sub> + <sub>...</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>m</sub>*
So basically we are moving down the matrix and summing all the columns there for the *Σ<sub>1</sub>*.
The next sums will be:
*Σ<sub>2</sub> = i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>1</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>2</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>3</sub> + <sub>...</sub> + i<sub>2</sub>j<sub>m</sub>*
*Σ<sub>3</sub> = i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>1</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>2</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>3</sub> + <sub>...</sub> + i<sub>3</sub>j<sub>m</sub>*
*Σ<sub>4</sub> = i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>1</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>2</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>3</sub> + <sub>...</sub> + i<sub>4</sub>j<sub>m</sub>*
And so on until we have
*Σ<sub>n</sub> = i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>1</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>2</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>3</sub> + <sub>...</sub> + i<sub>n</sub>j<sub>m</sub>*
Now, we have to move to the next column by increasing the index of the previous element by 1 and returning to the index of 1 of the last:
*Σ<sub>n+1</sub> = i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>1</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>2</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>3</sub> + <sub>...</sub> + i<sub>2</sub>j<sub>m-1</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>m</sub>*
After that, it's obvious to continue like in the first steps:
*Σ<sub>n+2</sub> = i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>1</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>2</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>3</sub> + <sub>...</sub> + i<sub>2</sub>j<sub>m-1</sub> + i<sub>2</sub>j<sub>m</sub>*
*Σ<sub>n+3</sub> = i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>1</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>2</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>3</sub> + <sub>...</sub> + i<sub>2</sub>j<sub>m-1</sub> + i<sub>3</sub>j<sub>m</sub>*
*Σ<sub>n+4</sub> = i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>1</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>2</sub> + i<sub>1</sub>j<sub>3</sub> + <sub>...</sub> + i<sub>2</sub>j<sub>m-1</sub> + i<sub>4</sub>j<sub>m</sub>*
Comparing all the sums *Σ* (until you'll be on a i<sub>n</sub>j<sub>m</sub>) you will have the largest sum!

---

To use this algorithm it's good to have `int matrix[n][m]` to store all the coins inside,
`int index[n][2]` to store the indexes of the elements in the sums (n number of indexes for 2 elements), and `int maxSum` to store the largest sum.